# Flutter Unable to stop Activity

Tags: android, flutter, service

I have a Flutter Application and use Services on native Android.
Now when I Stop the Application by pressing the Switch-Apps Button my Application crashes with this error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {de.karlw.time_management/de.karlw.time_management.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: de.karlw.time_management.MainActivity$1@f404173
E/AndroidRuntime( 8660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4861)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4826)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4906)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8660):    at android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute(StopActivityItem.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8660):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
```

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity implements MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {

static final String TAG = "rest";
static final String CHANNEL = "de.karlw.time_management/service";

AppService appService;
boolean serviceConnected = false;
MethodChannel.Result keepResult = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(this::onMethodCall);
}

@Override
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    try {
        if (call.method.equals("connect")) {
            connectToService();
            keepResult = result;
        } else if (serviceConnected) {
            if (call.method.equals("start")) {
                appService.startTimer();
                result.success(null);
            } else if (call.method.equals("stop")) {
                appService.stopTimer();
                result.success(null);
            } else if (call.method.equals("getCurrentSeconds")) {
                int sec = appService.getCurrentSeconds();
                result.success(sec);
            }
        } else {
            result.error(null, "App not connected to service", null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.error(null, e.getMessage(), null);
    }
}

private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        AppService.AppServiceBinder binder = (AppService.AppServiceBinder) service;
        appService = binder.getService();
        serviceConnected = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "Service connected");
        if (keepResult != null) {
            keepResult.success(null);
            keepResult = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        serviceConnected = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Service disconnected");
    }
};

private void connectToService() {
    if (!serviceConnected) {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, AppService.class);
        startService(service);
        getApplicationContext().bindService(service, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service already connected");
        if (keepResult != null) {
            keepResult.success(null);
            keepResult = null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getApplicationContext().unbindService(connection);
    serviceConnected = false;
}

}
```

I don't know why this happens. But I suggest the error is somehow the Service I use. But I have no clue why it happens.

Thanks for your help.